# Is matrix given by $(\sin x, \cos x)$ and $(0,0)$ vectors equivalent to matrix given by vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$

Tags: trigonometry, commutative-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $R=\mathbb{R}(\sin (x), \cos (x))$. Consider matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}
\sin (x) & 0\\
\cos (x) & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. Is it possible to find two matrices $A, B\in GL(2,R)$ s. t. $AMB=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$?

What if we consider $R$ to be some different ring, like $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, real-analytic functions on $\mathbb{R}$, $2\pi$-periodic real-analytic functions on $\mathbb{R}$?

I tried finding out something about that by myself, but I failed, having completely no clue how to proceed.
Question is similar to asking if $\begin{pmatrix}
X & 0 \\
Y & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ is equivalent to $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ in the ring $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$, but this is also a mystery to me. I was hoping that maybe presence of some additional data linked with trigonometric functions will be helpful (computations using power series, infinite product formulas or maybe Fourier series), but computations on matrices led me only to some necessary conditions on $A$ and $B$ (on which points of the real line some coefficients should vanish, one matrix is triangular etc.).

Comment: For your first question. Yes since all matrix of same rank are [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence)

Comment: @Walace, thank you kindly for an answer. Do you know any reference where I could find proof of this fact for matrices with coefficients in arbitrary ring? I read this article, but I thought it holds only for matrices with field coefficients (maybe local ring also).

Comment: I know this is true for element of $GL(n,R)$ where $R$ is $\mathbb R$. For rings a ring, I don't know, sorry. (I thought that $R$ mean $\mathbb R$, so I don't really answer to your question, sorry).

Comment: Thank you anyway for your time.